# Display image choice in true-false game

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a game in Swift to evaluate if Choice A is true or false compared to Choice B. The game works fine for strings but I would like to display images instead of strings (e.g. for `firstQuestion.choiceA = "A"`, don't show "A" but an image associated with A -- same for B). I've seen solutions for dictionaries to map strings to images or extracting and comparing image names but not sure how to implement in my case. The main parts of the code are enclosed. Does someone have sample code for how to do this in Swift for this case?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    class Questions {
        var question : String 
        var answer : String   
        var choiceA : String
        var choiceB : String

        init()  {
            question = ""
            answer = ""
            choiceA = ""
            choiceB = ""
        }

        func isCorrect(input : String) -> Bool  {
            return input == answer
        }    } 

    class QuestionGenerator {
        var questionList : [Questions] 
        var counter : Int           
        var currentQuestion : Questions/

        init() {
            questionList = [Questions]()
            counter = 0                 
            currentQuestion = Questions()
        }

        func addQuestion(question : Questions)  {
            questionList.append(question) 
        }

        func getNextQuestion() -> Questions {

            if (counter < questionList.count) {
                currentQuestion = questionList[counter]
                counter = counter + 1 
                return currentQuestion   
            }

            else 
            {
                counter = 0
                currentQuestion = questionList[counter]
                return currentQuestion
            }  }    }

        class Model  
    {

        var currentQuestion : Questions 
        var questionGen : QuestionGenerator 

        init()

        {
            let firstQuestion = Questions()
            firstQuestion.question = "Which one took longer?"
            firstQuestion.choiceA = "A"
            firstQuestion.choiceB = "B"
            firstQuestion.answer = firstQuestion.choiceA

            questionGen = QuestionGenerator() 
            questionGen.addQuestion(firstQuestion) 
        }

        func isCorrect(userInput : String) -> Bool
        {
            return userInput == currentQuestion.answer
        }   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two image view to display both images asociated to the answer in your storyboard. You can load this images views by using the name of the asstes or an url. If you decide to use the name of the assets this one could be the same name of the answer or you can add to the model two strings with imageA and imageB.

Then you simply load the image this way:

imageViewA.image=UIImage(named:currentQuestion.choiceA)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example of how to implement this in a playground.

Open the playground file in finder and create a folder called "Resources", drop two images in there (called "image" and "image2") and then copy this code into the playground.

```
import UIKit

enum AnswerOption {
    case Text(String)
    case Image(UIImage)
}

extension AnswerOption: Equatable { }
func ==(lhs: AnswerOption, rhs: AnswerOption) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (let .Text(str1), let .Text(str2)):
        return str1 == str2
    case (let .Image(img1), let .Image(img2)):
        return img1 == img2
    default:
        return false
    }
}

struct Question {
    let text: String
    let answer: AnswerOption
    let choiceA: AnswerOption
    let choiceB: AnswerOption

    init(text: String, choiceA: AnswerOption, choiceB: AnswerOption, answer: AnswerOption)  {
        self.text = text
        self.answer = answer
        self.choiceA = choiceA
        self.choiceB = choiceB
    }

    func isCorrect(input: AnswerOption) -> Bool  {
        return input == answer
    }
}

extension Question {
    func isCorrect(input: UIImage) -> Bool { return isCorrect(.Image(input)) }
    func isCorrect(input: String) -> Bool { return isCorrect(.Text(input)) }
}

extension Question {
    init(text: String, choiceA: String, choiceB: String, answer: String) {
        self.init(text: text, choiceA: .Text(choiceA), choiceB: .Text(choiceB), answer: .Text(answer))
    }

    init(text: String, choiceA: UIImage, choiceB: UIImage, answer: UIImage) {
        self.init(text: text, choiceA: .Image(choiceA), choiceB: .Image(choiceB), answer: .Image(answer))
    }
}

class QuestionGenerator {
    private var questions = [Question]()
    private var counter = 0
    private var currentQuestion: Question? {
        return counter < questions.count ? questions[counter] : nil
    }

    func addQuestion(question : Question)  {
        questions.append(question)
    }

    func getNextQuestion() -> Question {
        counter += 1
        if counter >= questions.count {
            counter = 0
        }
        return currentQuestion!
    }
}

// ====== Example usage ======

let questionGenerator = QuestionGenerator()
questionGenerator.addQuestion(Question(text: "Which one took longer?", choiceA: "A", choiceB: "B", answer: "A"))
questionGenerator.addQuestion(Question(text: "Which didn't take long at all?", choiceA: "A", choiceB: "B", answer: "B"))
let image = UIImage(named: "image")!
let image2 = UIImage(named: "image2")!
questionGenerator.addQuestion(Question(text: "Which one is the StackOverflow logo?", choiceA: image, choiceB: image2, answer: image))

var question = questionGenerator.currentQuestion!

print(question.isCorrect(question.choiceA) ? "Correct" : "Incorrect")
question = questionGenerator.getNextQuestion()
print(question.isCorrect("A") ? "Correct" : "Incorrect")
question = questionGenerator.getNextQuestion()
print(question.isCorrect(image) ? "Correct" : "Incorrect")
```

The enum `AnswerOption` can be either a string or an image, and the enum conforms to `Equatable`. With this solution, you can have images, string or anything else in the future.

My example might be a bit overkill but check it out in a playground and perhaps get some inspiration from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Outlet var QuestionLabel: UILabel!

Outlet var ButtonOne: UIButton!
Outlet var ButtonTwo: UIButton!
Outlet var OutputLabel: UILabel!
Action func checkAnswer(sender : UIButton)

let userInput = sender.titleLabel!.text

if(model.isCorrect(userInput!) == true)

{

   OutputLabel.text = "Good Job"
   let currentQuestion = model.getNextQuestion()
   QuestionLabel.text = currentQuestion.question
   ButtonOne.seTitle(currentQuestion.choiceA, forState:      UIControlState.Normal)
   ButtonTwo.setTitle(currentQuestion.choiceB, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

if (counter == 0)
{
    ButtonOne.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"A1"), for State: .Normal)
    ButtonTwo.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"B1"), for State: .Normal)
}
if (counter == 1)
{
    ButtonOne.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"A2"), for State: .Normal)
    ButtonTwo.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"B2"), for State: .Normal)
}

else
{
    OutputLabel.text = "Sorry"
}
```